# Store ISO 8601 Date format "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.ddddddZ" in Sybase version 15.0.3 as DateTime

Tags: sql, datetime, sybase, iso8601

I want to store the Date in Format `"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.ddddddZ"`in sybase as datetime .I am getting this date as a string for e.g.  `"2017-06-28T09:46:14.000028Z"` 
how can I store it in datetime/TimeStamp without loosing any precision/information ?

Comment: FWIW, Sybase ASE has the `bigdatetime` and `bigtime` datatypes that can store data to the microsecond, though I don't think these datatypes are available until 15.5

Answer (score 0):

Your string, "2017-06-28T09:46:14.000028Z" ends in Z, and the Z indicates a time zone, Zulu time, better known an GMT.

Sybase ASE does not have a date time type that accepts a time zone. You can store the rest of it without the time zone, and have a convention that that data is in GMT.